# How to kill LAMBDA hot container to refresh all data from RDS connection.pool

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am noticing that under some conditions Lamda is using `old data` form an rds connection.pool after I have update both the Lamda function and the RDS data.

For example.

```
V1 of function is uploaded to lambda via cli
V1 is tested @ lambda aws.web.console and returns data as expected
V1 is called from api.gateway and returns v1 data as expected

V2 of function is uploaded to lambda via cli
V2 data is changed on RDS 
V2 is tested @ lambda aws.web.console and returns V2 data as expected
V2 is called from api.gateway and returns data as **V1**
```

Wait for function to go cold

```
V2 is called from api.gateway and returns V2 data as expected
```

It seems that,

1. the aws.web.console always calls a new container and new connection.pools when testing the function
2. calls from api.gateway seems to use a previous container with old cache or a new container with old cache somehow?

So my question is how do you force kill a Lambda function so it goes cold and restarts completely new on next call?

Comment: Seems like you're storing the result of your lambda _outside_ of your handler. In which case, it will be susceptible to container reuse. Care to share relevant parts of your code? e.g. How is the connection created?

Comment: The best way I've found for forcing a cold start is to re-deploy the code, but you should really look into @dashmug's point about the data being susceptible to container reuse.

Comment: @dashmug, I have declared an array outside of `handler`, we have now moved all vars inside and will test. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @artvanderlay I've moved my comment as an answer. When you verify that it fixes your problem, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update (May 22, 2018)**: As of this writing, the only way to use new containers is by re-deploying code. The OP's problem is fixed by changing his code as this answer below suggests so there is no more need to redeploy code.

---

Seems like you're storing the result of your lambda outside of your handler. In which case, it will be susceptible to container reuse.

Anything declared outside the handler will be shared across invocations so make sure you declare/initialize variables that are specific to that invocation (e.g. request) **inside** the handler function.

Comment: I am not sure that this answers the question. Reusing connections is a good thing™, what the question asked was how to force the reload when you know the connection is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

I found an interesting way to kill it which may help.
Please refer : https://www.edureka.co/community/41976/how-to-kill-a-lambda-function-in-aws

Pay attention to the answer:
"You cannot kill a running lambda function. Though there is another way by which you can set concurrency limit to 0. This will stop it from starting any more executions"

```
$ aws lambda put-function-concurrency --function-name my-function --reserved-concurrent-executions 0
```